# Adding record to Table (foreign key constraint fails)

Tags: mysql, sql, record

I have problem with adding some records to my table (grupy, login(VARCHAR 32, Primary Key, Unique), grupa(VARCHAR 10).

When I try this script:

```
ALTER TABLE `grupy` ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `grupy` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `login` ) REFERENCES `issi`.`pracownicy` (`login`) ON DELETE CASCADE;


INSERT INTO `grupy` (`login`, `grupa`) VALUES
('administrator', 'zalogowany');
```

I got a error:

> Error code 1452, SQL state 23000: Cannot add or update a child row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails (`issi`.`grupy`, CONSTRAINT
>   `grupy_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`login`) REFERENCES `pracownicy` (`login`)
>   ON DELETE CASCADE) Line 6, column 1

What   did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens when an existing value is invalid -- i.e. not in the table.   You can check for invalid values easily enough:

```
select g.*
from grupy g
where not exists (select 1 from issi.pracownicy p on p.login = g.login);
```

If this is the case, change the existing values (say, to `NULL`) and then add the constraint.

Comment: Thanks for yours advice. Problem was just little bit stupid. I have ran script in NetBeans 8, I tried MySQL Front, and there it worked. I'm little bit confused.